# jQuery Changing Label (date) based on SQL database being queried by CF

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

I have a SQL database table named dbo.Holidays that I am querying using ColdFusion. The goal I am trying to do is have the label not include the holiday days or weekends. So when a holiday is listed or its the weekend it will display the next available day. For example if today (thursday) 10/15/15, the label will show "DUE 10/16/15 @ 5:00". But if tomorrow (friday) 10/16/15, the label will show "DUE 10/19/15 @ 5:00". And the same would apply for holidays it would be the next available day and not on the weekend. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

I have a textarea like so:

```
<div id="DTmrw" class="col-xs-12">
  <label class="centered" for="DueTmrw">DUE (Tomorrow --10/16/15) @ 5:00</label>
  <textarea class="form-control" rows="7"></textarea>
</div>
```

CFC Function

```
<cffunction name="Holidays" access="public" returntype="query">
    <cfset var getHolidays = ''>
    <cfquery name="getHolidays">
        SELECT date
        FROM dbo.Holidays
    </cfquery>
    <cfreturn getHolidays>
</cffunction>
```

Table: dbo.Holidays
[image]

What I have tried:

```
<cfquery name="getHolidays">
  select holiday, date
  from dbo.Holidays
</cfquery>

<cfset aryData  = [] />

<cfloop from="1" to="#getHolidays.recordcount#" index="j">
  <cfset ArrayAppend(aryData, DateFormat(getHolidays.date[j], "yyyy-mm-dd")) />
</cfloop>

<cfoutput>
  <cfdump var="#getHolidays#">
</cfoutput>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
var getHolidays = <cfoutput>#serializeJson(aryData)#</cfoutput>; 
console.log(getHolidays);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also have a database table that identifies holidays.  I have used it to write a ColdFusion function called isBusinessDay that takes a date as an argument, and returns true or false.  The logic in the function is a combination of using ColdFusion functions to identify weekends and the database table to identify holidays.

Let's assume that you have written a version of that function using your own database table.  You now need to find the next business day, starting on a given date.  You can do something like this:

```
 dateIWant = someDateYouCanCreate;
 isBusinessDay = theFunctionYouWrote(dateIWant);

 while (isBusinessDay == false) {
 dateIWant = dateAdd("d", 1, dateIWant);
 isBusinessDay = theFunctionYouWrote(dateIWant);
 }
```

Comment: Vicki - not too tough. 1) take the date and extract the day of the week from it - your DB has a built in for that (datepart() In SQL) then compare it to see if it IS or is NOT a weekday. For example (from memory)  MSSQL returns 1 from Sun and 7 for Sat. So if your datapart is 2 through 6 you are on a weekday. Savvy?

Comment: Why do you need js at all?

Comment: I like this approach. The only think I would do different is make an SQL function that way there are fewer trips to the db.

Comment: you like which approach? man I wish I could wrap my mind around this CF stuff http://jsfiddle.net/byyeh83t/1/ I have it figured out with JS if I can figure out how to take the query and turn it into the JS array like I have in the fiddle for `var natDays`

Comment: @DanBracuk I am so close the date is not putting the commas where I need though

Answer (score -1):

I have not tested this, may have some typos, but this is a general idea on how you can make this happen.

```
<cffunction name="checkHoliday">
  <cfargument name="checkDate" type="numeric" required="yes">
  <cfquery name="checkHolidays" datasource="#request.dsn#">
    select * from holidays where [date] = '#dateFormat(t,"YYYY-MM-DD")#'
  </cfquery>
  <cfif checkHoldays.recordCount gt 0>
    <cfset temp = checkHoliday(arguments.checkDate++)>
  <cfelse>
    <cfreturn arguments.checkDate>
  </cfif>
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="getDueDate" access="public" output="no">
  <cfargument name="due" type="string" required="no" default="#now()#">
  <cfset var workingDate = fix(arguments.due)++>      
  <cfset t = dayOfWeek(workingDate)>
  <cfif listFind("5,6",t)>
   <!--- then we know this is a weekend --->
    <cfset t = (7-t) + t>
   <!--- move to Monday --->
  </cfif>
  <!--- check it our date is on a holiday recursively --->
  <cfreturn dateFormat(checkHoliday(t),"YYYY-MM-DD")>
</cffunction>
```

Comment: Your checkHoliday function should use dates, not numbers.